# XaResourceRecoveryManager : Error while retrieving xids from resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Getting the above warning while starting my spring application.

```
WARN com.atomikos.recovery.xa.XaResourceRecoveryManager - Error while retrieving xids from resource - will retry later...
```

The server starts properly, but i still dont know why these warning are logged in my logs.
Any solution would help me.

Comment: Maybe this (http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default.asp?community.6.3514.8) blog entry can point you to the right direction

Comment: I didn't find any solution over there.

Comment: if this warnings are while connecting to DB then you need to provide access to XA datasource to 2pc commit

Answer (score 1):

This error could appear if you didn't configure Oracle for XA for Atomikos
https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringOracleForXA